# Change between dark and light keyboard iOS7

Tags: ios, ipad, keyboard, tint

In iOS7 we have both a dark and a light keyboard. Is it possible for me to change between these in my app by code?[image: Dark keyboard] [image: Light keyboard]

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
textfield.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearanceDark;
```

Answer (score 4):

in Swift 3:

```
textfield.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearance.dark
```

Comment: textfield.keyboardAppearance = .dark

Comment: Works in Swift 4, too. Add to view did load or someplace similar.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else that finds this question from google, you can also make the keyboard dark from the storyboard as well.

[image]