# Trigger iOS dark keyboard from HTML input

Tags: html, ios, css, keyboard

I am writing a web app (for the iPad) which has a night mode, which inverts the colours to white text on a black background for use in low light. However, the inputs trigger the standard iOS keyboard, which is glaringly bright. I already know how to trigger the numeric keyboard, but is there a way to suggest to mobile Safari to present the dark keyboard instead of the light one?

Comment: I don't think that is possible.

Comment: It's not possible. (You can only hope that iOS will be updated with support for dark mode in the future like they did with Mohave.)

Comment: If iOS doesn't supports dark one, then you'll have to make one yourself!

Answer (score 10):

Unfortunately the appearance of the keyboard depends entirely on the user, there is no way to change the appearance of the keyboard in ios, what you can do is wait for a future update to have this addition, but for the apple system used to be very closed I think it is unlikely

Edit: you can try to make your own virtual keyboard like this one: https://gate2home.com/English-Keyboard

Update: For the new iphone, and those upgrading to IOS 13, native dark mode will be available, but this mode can only be used if the user wishes, you have no way to activate it through your website or app.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, you can award bounty to your ownself? I thought the system wouldn't allow it.

Comment: no, I can't, but sometimes I do this to see if anyone can answer more fully

Answer (score 4):

### Short Answer: No you can't.

My how far we've come in 4 years. Sadly the question "Can I specify the iOS UI theme from inside a webapp" is still a resounding NO. *(And really would you want iOS to allow anyone else to decide how your device looks?)*

As of fall 2019, about the only iOS element you can theme from a web app is the `status bar`. This is great for Progressive Web Apps but not if you want to control other UI elements.

### A better solution

The OP's original question was really more about supporting a dark theme which we can assume the user chose to activate (allowing Night Mode timer is basically a user choice).

**As of 2019, we CAN support the user's choice of themes.** Both Android 9 and iOS 13 support global dark and light themes. This means that the keyboard element (among others) will respect the chosen mode. Now, all we need to do is let our web apps/sites respect those settings as well.

This basically means that when a user who has specified a "dark theme" on their device loads your HTML, you can support that choice in your own code. Doing this is pretty simple thanks to a **CSS Media Query test** called `prefers-color-scheme`. Options are `no-preference`, `light` and `dark`. No preference is basically the default or it means there's no device support.

Usage is quite simple. Since most of us probably build a "light" theme first you can simply override your light colors with darker ones.

```css
/* it's never a good idea to do full black on full white
 or full white on full black since it's hard on our eyes */

body {
  background: #ffffff;
  color: #333333;
  font-family: Sans-Serif;
  font-size: 62.5%;
  /* etc, etc, etc */
}


/* media query to override the default */
@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark){
  body {
    background: #171717;
    color: #f7f7f7;
  }
}
```

Now the correct keyboard will load by default (based on user preference) now it's the job of apps/sites to support that user's choice.

#### Support

This technique will support user-defined theme preferences in Safari on iOS 13, Chrome on Android, and Safari, Chrome & Firefox on Mac OS 10.14 (Mojave).

Answer (score 0):

Apple announces [dark mode](https://www.apple.com/ios/ios-13-preview/) today with ios 13. And as per the official documentation. Dark Mode is also available to third-party app developers for integration into their own apps, and can be scheduled to turn on automatically at sunset or at a certain time.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is a bit outdated but maybe these answers will help you find out the solution.

[This one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19272506) is quite old but [the second one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49827310) is from last year so it may actually help.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using the input to get the user's credentials you might want to use the "password" type input field the keyboard triggered in that case would be dark one.

```
    <input type="password" />
```